# How to limit application windows to only windows in the active desktop/workspace?

Tags: keyboard, mission-control, ui, application-switcher

In Mission Control, there's the Application windows keybinding setting, which when invoked shows all windows from your current application, across all of your desktops.

[image: mission control]

Is there a way to somehow limit this to only show the windows that are present on your active desktop?

Comment: Spaces doesn't really support multiple desktops per app, so I doubt you'll be able to do this.

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. I know on GNOME you can for different desktops, which is the behavior I'd like. Oh well then.